# Stop browser locking during (synchronous) Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, synchronous

What I am trying to do is append a loading image to a div (so the user knows something is loading) and then I call a jquery ajax function, which is set to "async: false".  Here is my code:

```
$jQuery("#playersListDiv").html(loadingImage);    
$jQuery.ajax({
         type: "POST", /* this goesn't work with GET */
         url: urlValue, /*ex: "NBAgetGamesList.php" */
         data: parameters, /*ex: "param1=hello" */
         cache: false,
         async: false,
                     success: function(data){

                     }
});
```

The problem is that the browser locks and does not append the loading image until AFTER the ajax call is done which is useless of course.  Firefox is the only browser that actually appends the loading image.  IE, Chrome, and Safari DO NOT append the loading image.

I know browser locking happens because async is set to false but this is my only option because I have to wait for this request to complete before continuing because I need the data that is returned.

Is there any way around this?  If I place an alert after the I append the loading image that works but I don't want an alert popping up every time.

Comment: Synchronous, by definition, is "blocking". How it will affect browsers varies but usually blocks DOM updates and interaction. Make it asynchronous to "fix" the problem.

Comment: Why not just make it asynchronous and put the code to run after this in a separate function. Then call the function in the return code?

Comment: "because I need the data that is returned." That is what callbacks are for. Your code does not have to be linear.

Comment: @Bob put what code after this?  Epacscarello, there is a callback function.  In this case it does need to be linear because I am waiting for data and then I use that data in the next block of code.

Comment: @Ray - what they're saying (and as shown in my answer) is that you can move the entire next block of code into the success callback, or put it in a separate function that you call from the success callback, and then that block can make use of the returned data.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Despite your assertion to the contrary you don't *need* it to be synchronous. Whatever you need to do with/after the response can be done in the success (and/or error or complete) callback. So change:

```
$jQuery("#playersListDiv").html(loadingImage);    
$jQuery.ajax({
   ...
   async: false,
   ...
});
// OTHER CODE
```

to be like this:

```
$jQuery("#playersListDiv").html(loadingImage);    
$jQuery.ajax({
   ...
   async: true,
   success: function(data) {
      // OTHER CODE
   }
});
```

Or move "OTHER CODE" to a separate function that you call from the success callback.

If you need something more complicated than that you could encapsulate the above in a function and pass a callback to it:

```
function doAjaxStuff(callback) {
    $jQuery("#playersListDiv").html(loadingImage);    
    $jQuery.ajax({
       ...
       async: true,
       success: function(data) {
          // optional other processing here, then:
          callback(data);
       }
    });
}

// then from somewhere else in your code:
doAjaxStuff(function(data) {
   // do something with data
});
```

Comment: That's exactly what I already have.  A success/callback function.  The browser is locked until after the callback function is complete.

Comment: It's _not_ what you already have: change your code to `async:true` (or omit the parameter entirely and it should default to `async : true`).

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear.  I tried "async: true" originally and the code doesn't even work at all.  That was the reason why I went to false in the first place.  My goal was to figure out a way of getting this to work with "async: false".

Comment: You can't. `async:false` _will_ lock up the browser, regardless of whether you manage to get the image to display first. (Though if you don't care if the browser is locked as long as the image gets displayed you could set the image before calling your function, then instead of calling the function directly use `setTimeout(yourFunction, 5);` - the browser may then display the image before starting your function. But really I do _not_ recommend that at all. Much better to restructure the code to work with an asynchronous request.

Comment: Alright thanks for your help I'll just restructure my code later.  I thought there would be an easy way around it.

Answer (score -1):

What you want is [jQuery.Deferred()](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

Answer (score -1):

I came across this issue and I found a solution for it.

Suppose! you are really in need to use `async : false` in your `ajax request` and  you want to show a loading Image while execution of `ajax` request. But `ajax` request is halting other UI operation (displaying of loading image) due to `async : false`. So, the simple solution for it, Use [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) to display loading image and [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) to hide loading image.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmushtaq/z9ee1svr/) demo which contains a `ajax` request with `async : false`. Due to this, the loading Image in not displaying. (I used [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/) method to display loading image.).

Here is another [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmushtaq/6zmj3xaL/) with fadeIn and fadeOut effect. It displays loading image regardless of `async : false` in `ajax` request.