# displaying text while json function is executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

my requirement is : when user clicks on a button until the data is fetched, display a text "Searching...". I am using a JSON function to fetch data.
But the problem is I am able to display the "Searching ..." text on button click only in Firefox, not in chrome or IE. I have tried beforeSend also, but even tat works only in Firefox. I have read that async =false, is causing this issue, but i need synchronous call only for this.

```
<span id="searchWait" >&nbsp;</span>

<script>
function getPromptSearchResults() {
    $('#searchWait').html('Searching...');

    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: 'Application.aspx/getPromptSearchResults',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            some parameters
        }),
        success: function (data) {
            $('#searchWait').html('');
            something
        },
        error: function (parameters) {
            something
        }
    });

    return something;
}
</script>
```

Comment: I don't see where you're displaying the search text.  It's always hidden.

Comment: that style was a typo. I have corrected it. IE/ Chrome/Safari block all requests in async false, how to address this issue. I have read callbacks address it. How,  to use callback here?

Comment: please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755485/stop-browser-locking-during-synchronous-ajax. It resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `$('#searchWait').show();` so that it changes the style attribute and is no longer hidden.

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/zLnED/

That isn't my fiddle, but I would recommend changing the timeout to 100-500 for more reliability.

Comment: show and hide is not the issue, that style was a typo. I have corrected it. IE Chrome all browsers block all requests in asyn false, how to address this issue. I have read callbacks address it. How to use callback here?

Comment: The only thing I would suggest is to put `$('#searchWait').html('Searching...');` in it's own function and call `getPromptSearchResults` from  that function. Also use `console.log` statements to debug how your code is executing.

Comment: i already tried that, it doesnt work as browser gets blocked when u set async as false.

Comment: I have added a fiddle from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7301654/1165441 it seems to accomplish what you need.

Comment: thanks, but since i am expecting this json function to return data i am getting error... will callback with promise resolve this issue? If yes how to implement it?

Comment: What error are you getting? The fiddle technically returns data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755485/stop-browser-locking-during-synchronous-ajax  .... ppl with similar issues please check if this link will help you, it resolves my issue...

Comment: edhedges this timeout did not return me any data, and so caused an error. and increasing time out causes unnecessary delay, which is not an efficient solution. Anyway thanks for the effort.